# Databinding of observablecollection in wpf and fill the gui in a special order

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, collections, itemscontrol

I'm trying to create my gui as much with databinding as possible. There for I have collection of channels which also have list of steps. What I know want is to bind those collections to xaml elements and get them displayed in the following order:

```
Channel1 step1 step2 step3 step4
Channel2 step1 step2 step3 step4
```

I tried it with nested ItemsControls like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=channels}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=steps}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                             <GUI:stepAnalog></GUI:stepAnalog>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

But all I achieved is something like ordering the elements like:

```
channel1 step1 step2 step3 channel2 step1 step2 step3
```

or

```
channel1
step1
step2
step3
channel2
step1
step2
step3
```

Is there a solution in wpf with just using databindings or do I have to do it programmatically by iterating over the elements and place them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres always a solution, its just a matter of finding the right one!

I would suggest playing with the ItemsPanel of you ItemsControls like so:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=channels}"> 
        <!-- This specifies that the items in the top level items control should be stacked vertically-->
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> 
    <DataTemplate> 
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=steps}"> 
                <!-- This specifies that the items in the second level items control should be stacked horizontally-->
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>               
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> 
                     <DataTemplate> 
                         <GUI:stepAnalog></GUI:stepAnalog> 
                    </DataTemplate> 
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> 
            </ItemsControl> 
    </DataTemplate> 
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

This allows you to specify how the items in the items control are layed out, and you can still use your DataTemplate to define how they are displayed